# Do I need to rotate jornald?

Tags: docker, logging, systemd

I want to use journald as logging driver of docker. As I am not familiar with journald, I am worried that the logging file may exhaust the storage of the host. Do I need to rotate journald somehow? If so, how?

Comment: [`man journald.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)

Comment: Mind you, run `man journald.conf` on _your_ system. Systemd is fairly new and in active development; not all distributions have all features.